# MVC ASP-NET Core. Views y Controllers dentro de subdirectorios

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en ASP.NET Core MVC y tengo unas cuestiones respecto a la estructura de los controladores y vistas.
En resumen, la aplicación tiene la misma estructura para dos tipos de usuarios, Company e Investor.

La aplicación detecta que clase de usuario se ha logueado y cambia los links del menu al formato `Company/[controller]/[action]` o `Investor/[controller]/[action]`

La estructura de directorios es la siguiente:

[image: Imagen estructura de directorios]

Los controladores tienen la siguiente etiqueta de enrutado que funciona bien:

```
[Route("/Company/[controller]/[action]")]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{...
```

Estoy teniendo problemas con las vistas, que tienen la misma estructura de directorios, ya que no detecta la vista correspondiente. He de ponerle en cada Action a `return View("Views/Company/Dashboard/Dashboard.cshtml")` con toda la ruta hasta la vista y eso me huele mal. Lo mismo me pasa con las vistas que tienen renders parciales a otras vistas en el mismo subdirectorio.

Ejemplo: `Company/Dashboard/Dashboard.cshtml` contiene:

```
<partial name="Users" />
```

Siendo`Users.cshtml`una vista en el mismo directorio q `Dashboard.cshtml`

```
InvalidOperationException: The partial view 'Users' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Dashboard/Users.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Users.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Users.cshtml
```

¿Es esta la mejor forma de estructurar una aplicación con estas características?

¿Hay alguna forma de decirle a MVC que use otra ruta para las vistas?

Gracias.

**EDITADO:**

Una solución es añadir una clase que implemente `IViewLocationExpander`

```
   public class ViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
        {
            string[] locations = new[] 
            {
                "/Views/Company/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "/Views/Investor/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
            };

            return locations.Union(viewLocations);
        }

        public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
        {
            context.Values["customviewlocation"] = nameof(ViewLocationExpander); 
        }
    }
```

Y registrarla con...

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new ViewLocationExpander());
            });
```

Ahora la aplicación detecta bien la vista PERO siempre me selecciona la primera en el caso que entre como Company o como Investor, y es que el menú no tengo forma de indicarle uno y otro Controller

¿Hay alguna forma de indicárselo?

```
                <li><a asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="Index">Company Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action="Index">Investor Dashboard</a></li>
```

Comment: Lo que necesitas es checar sobre el tema de 'areas' https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: usando `asp-area`

Answer (score 0):

Si el contenido depende del perfil pero el template y la logica es la misma entonces no tienes porque repetir el codigo en ningun lado.

Lo correcto es que en el controlador preguntas por el rol del usuario y con base en ello modificas la lógica, incluso dentro del controlador puedes cambiar la vista a utilizar dependiendo del perfil.

Ten en cuenta que una cosa es la ruta de acceso al 'endpoint' y otra cosa es la vista que renderizas,

En cada controller puedes hacer algo como para establecer tu mismo que vista deseas renderizar, y esto es totalmente independiente del Route que usas para invocar el endpoint (Controller)

```
return View("~/Views/Wherever/SomeDir/MyView.aspx");
```